# pointer to derived class in base class constructor

Tags: c++, pointers, constructor, hierarchical-data

(Note that this is an oversimplification of my actual design.)

Given the following:

```
class CParentA;
class C_Child
public:
    C_Child(C_ParentB* parent) : m_parent(parent){}; 
    virtual ~C_Child();

    CParentB*   m_parent;

};

class C_ParentA : public C_Child
{
public:
    C_ParentA(C_GrandParent *gp) : C_Child(gp){};
    virtual ~C_ParentA(){};
}

class C_ParentB
{
public:
    C_ParentB(){};
    virtual ~C_ParentB(){};
    void    foo(){};

}

class C_GrandParent : public C_ParentB, public C_ParentA
{
public:
    C_GrandParent() : C_ParentA(this){};
    virtual ~C_GrandParent();

}


main()
{
    C_GrandParent   gp;

    gp.m_parent->foo();
}
```

It seems that `parentB`'s pointer, sent to the child's constructor, isn't valid yet when the grandparent is created. I had thought that, even if the parent wasn't fully constructed, it's pointer (`this`) would still be valid. I've also tried having `ParentB` be a pointer stored in the `grandparent`, and the object dynamically created in the `grandparent` constructor. But that apparently has the same outcome.

FWIW: the goal of this: `grandparent` has many `parents`, some of them with `children`. One `child` may need access to another `child` or a `parent` (`uncle`/`cousin`). I had thought that having them all under one patriarch would handle much of the inter-relationships between family members. While that is the case, setting the appropriate pointers seems to be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

First, is is not clear what you are asking, so I am just trying to speculate. You present a design that is not working so you must be asking for alternatives, but you give no information on what you are trying to do.

Second, when class `A` derives a class `B` we usually say `B` is the base or parent and `A` is the derived or child. You use the opposite terminology and this is very confusing.

Now, I only assume that `CParentB* m_parent;` in `C_Child` is supposed to refer to the same `C_Child` object, viewed as `CParentB`. You don't need to store a pointer for this. Given a `C_Child& r` reference or `C_Child* p` pointer, you can simply say respectively

```
dynamic_cast<CParentB&>(r)
dynamic_cast<CParentB*>(p)
```

Both will fail in different ways if `r,p` do not refer to a `CParentB` object. `dynamic_cast` lets you navigate the entire class hierarchy and check at run time if a cast is valid. If the classes are not polymorphic, you can use `static_cast` instead.

In any case, keep in mind that before any object of a derived class is fully constructed, its bases need to constructed first. So before that, avoid playing in any way with the partially constructed object, like calling its methods especially virtual ones.

Comment: Sorry about the hierarchy order - I was renaming from my actual design, and got things reversed. Consider `grandparent` as `Container`, and `parents` as objects within that container, some of which contain other objects. Various objects within the container need access to other objects within it as well. That's what I am trying to get to. I thought I could pass `this` for the `Container` object to all objects within it. While it compiled ok, the actual pointer to the `Container` wasn't valid yet. And, yes, as you point out, I do make sure I don't use that pointer until all is built.